# How to remove a large number of unused keywords from Apple Photos app?

Tags: applescript, photos.app

My Photo library has evolved over many years, starting out as an iPhoto library, then being merged with an Aperture library, then becoming a Photos library.  Over the course of the last 20 or so years I've accumulated thousands of keywords that have zero photos associated with them.

The Photos app itself does not support a 'Delete unused keywords' feature, and I have looked at using AppleScript to do this, but, despite being quite an experienced programmer, I could not work out how to do this (AppleScript drives me nuts quite honestly).

I'm hoping someone has already written such a script, or if not a script then some other utility that will do this for me.

Comment: That would be fine.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a script I wrote and tested over quite a few days.  Whilst Apple's *Photos.app* **is** scriptable, you've already observed that it lacks the necessary methods to delete unused keywords.  If you are familiar with AppleScript and the notion of UI scripting, this appears to be the only option available.

**Note:** For UI scripting to work, you need to provide the necessary [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) to *Script Editor*.

My personal view towards UI scripting is generally a negative one, but I have taken extra care to try and mitigate the typical temperamental nature and fragility of UI scripts, and done a few tests on my system to observe a reasonably smooth operation.

*However*, the one specific feature I couldn't (wasn't willing to) check during testing is how the script performs when there are thousands of keywords, and/or an extremely large *Photos* library.  I myself have a *Photos* library consisting of fewer than 100 photos, and none of them had been tagged with keywords, so I created a sample of 20, of which I randomly assigned about half of them.

In theory, the only affect library volume or keyword count should have on script operation is the length of time it takes to execute.  But, with AppleScript, there may be timeout issues that prematurely abort the script; and with UI scripting, the probability of it throwing an error tends to increase with running time.

Specific notes regarding these uncertainties on performance are expanded upon below the script.  If you run into any issues, please report back and I shall consider how to implement a fix.  There ought to be no adverse effects should the script not perform ideally (i.e. you **won't** lose any photos).  Suboptimal performance ought to only result in an incomplete purge of keywords.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# pnam: PHOTOS#DELETE UNUSED KEYWORDS
# nmxt: .applescript
# pDSC: A UI scripting-dependent script to remove keywords from Photos.app that
#       have not been assigned to any photos

# plst: -

# rslt: «list» : On successful completion, the script reacquires an updated
#                list of disused keywords and returns the result (hopefully
#                an empty list)
#       «err » : Script failure throws an error.  Running the script again
#                with Photos.app already open may yield a different result.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# sown: CK
# ascd: 2019-01-07
# asmo: 2019-01-07
# vers: 1.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
use sys : application "System Events"
use Photos : application "Photos"

property process : a reference to application process "Photos"

property _M : a reference to every media item
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# IMPLEMENTATION:
activate Photos
open the keywordManager

set everyKeyword to the list of allKeywords()
set activeKeywords to the list of currentKeywords()
set disusedKeywords to difference(everyKeyword, activeKeywords)

tell the keywordManager
    tell its keywordEditor
        open it
        select disusedKeywords
        delete
        close
    end tell
end tell

set everyKeyword to the list of allKeywords()
set activeKeywords to the list of currentKeywords()

close the keywordManager

set disusedKeywords to difference(everyKeyword, activeKeywords)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HANDLERS & SCRIPT OBJECTS:
script keywordManager
    property window : a reference to window "Keywords" of my process
    property scroll area : a reference to scroll area 2 of my window
    property button : a reference to button "Edit Keywords" of my window
    property menu item : a reference to ¬
        (menu item "Keyword Manager" of ¬
            menu 1 of ¬
            menu bar item "Window" of ¬
            menu bar 1 of my process)

    script keywordEditor
        property title : "Manage My Keywords"
        property window : a reference to window title of my process
        property scroll area : a reference to scroll area 1 ¬
            of my window
        property table : a reference to table 1 of my scroll area
        property group : a reference to group 1 of my window
        property button : a reference to (first button of my group ¬
            whose accessibility description = "remove")
        property menu item : a reference to ¬
            (menu item "Select All" of ¬
                menu 1 of ¬
                menu bar item "Edit" of ¬
                menu bar 1 of my process)
        to open
            if my window exists then return
            tell the keywordManager to if not ¬
                (its window exists) then ¬
                open it

            click the keywordManager's button
            with timeout of 10 seconds
                repeat until the my window exists
                    delay 0.5
                end repeat
            end timeout
            perform action "AXRaise" of my window
        end open

        to close
            if not (my window exists) then return
            click button "OK" of my window
        end close

        to select |keywords| as list
            local |keywords|

            set focused of my table to true

            click my menu item

            script deselect
                property list : |keywords|
                on fn(x)
                    if the value of x's text field 1 ¬
                        is not in my list then
                        set x's selected to false
                        return true
                    end if
                    false
                end fn
            end script

            filterItems from rows of my table ¬
                given handler:deselect
        end select

        to delete
            if not (my button exists) then return 0
            click my button
        end delete
    end script

    on menuItem()
        tell my menu item to if exists then return it
        false
    end menuItem

    to open
        if my window exists then return false
        tell the keywordEditor to if ¬
            (its window exists) then ¬
            return close it

        click my menuItem()

        # tell sys to keystroke "k" using command down

        with timeout of 10 seconds
            repeat until my window exists
                delay 0.5
                set my process's frontmost to true
            end repeat
        end timeout
        perform action "AXRaise" of my window
    end open

    to close
        if not (my window exists) then return
        click (value of attribute "AXCloseButton" of my window)
    end close
end script

on allKeywords()
    script |keywords|
        property list : accessibility description of ¬
            every checkbox of the keywordManager's scroll area ¬
            whose role description = "keyword checkbox"
    end script
end allKeywords

on currentKeywords()
    script
        property keep : keywords of _M
        property list : strings in unique_(flatten_(keep))
    end script
end currentKeywords

on __(function)
    if the function's class = script ¬
        then return the function

    script
        property fn : function
    end script
end __

to filterItems from L as list into R as list : missing value ¬
    given handler:function
    local L, R

    if R = missing value then set R to {}

    script
        property list : L
        property result : R
    end script

    tell the result to repeat with x in its list
        if __(function)'s fn(x, its list, its result) ¬
            then set end of its result to x's contents
    end repeat

    R
end filterItems

to foldItems from L at |ξ| : 0 given handler:function
    local L, |ξ|, function

    script
        property list : L
    end script

    tell the result to repeat with i from 1 to length of its list
        set x to item i in its list
        tell __(function)'s fn(x, |ξ|, i, L) to ¬
            if it = missing value then
                exit repeat
            else
                set |ξ| to it
            end if
    end repeat

    |ξ|
end foldItems

on difference(A as list, B as list)
    local A, B

    script
        on notMember(M)
            script
                on fn(x)
                    x is not in M
                end fn
            end script
        end notMember
    end script

    filterItems from A given handler:result's notMember(B)
end difference

on union(A as list, B as list)
    local A, B

    script
        on insert(x, L)
            set end of L to x
            L
        end insert
    end script

    foldItems from A at B given handler:result's insert
end union

to flatten:L
    foldItems from L at {} given handler:union
end flatten:

on unique:L
    local L

    script
        on notMember(x, i, L)
            x is not in L
        end notMember
    end script

    filterItems from L given handler:result's notMember
end unique:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------❮END❯
```

#### Uncertainties on Threats to Performance

1. **Regarding the volume of photos in your library**, the line I am most mindful about is this one:

   ```
   property _M : a reference to every media item
   ```

   the effect of which will come into play at the points in the script where the property is dereferenced, i.e.

   ```
   set activeKeywords to the list of currentKeywords()
   ```

   The function of this line is to retrieve a list of all keywords currently assigned to at least one photo.  In order to do this, every single photo in your library needs to be enumerated (retrieved), and its `keywords` property evaluated.  This happens virtually immediately at the start of the script; and again after purging keywords to determine if the purge was complete.  It's a time-consuming process, and therefore a potential timeout threat for the script.

   One ought to be able to extend the default timeout value like so:
       with timeout of 600 seconds
           set activeKeywords to the list of currentKeywords()
       end timeout

   or it may be necessary to slightly alter the syntax in retrieving the photos so that the script directly targets the *Photos* app at the point of enumeration, instead of by way of property references; and *then* to enclose the *Photos* command within a `timeout` block.  But, for now, I've left it to see if the script will run on your system using the default timeout, which might not be a constraint if the enumeration takes place synchronously (and I don't know whether or not it does).
2. **Regarding UI scripting potential roadblocks:** the *Photos* AppleScript dictionary doesn't provide a way to retrieve all keywords that exist in the app.  The way the script works around this is to open up the *Keyword Manager* and read off the name of every keyword label that it detects under the section `"Keywords"`.  What I don't know is whether every UI element containing a keyword label is loaded when the *Keyword Manager* window gets created; or whether they get loaded piecewise when a user scrolls through the list.  The latter situation would be irksome, as it would result in an incomplete list of keywords and then an incomplete purge.

   One obvious solution would be to run the script multiple times to perform multiple purges until the are no remaining purgeable items.
3. **When considering the worst-case scenario**, analysing the script appears to have one of three possible outcomes (regardless of how the script terminates, be it through completion of its run or by throwing an error):

   - **Either** the script does nothing (nil result);
   - **OR** an incomplete purge occurs (partial success);
   - **OR** a complete purge occurs (success).

   There *does not seem* to be a way for the script to fail in a way that negatively impacts the *Photos* library, so the worst-case scenario appears to be the *nil result*.  However, if we assume I can be wrong, you may want to put a margin on error on the potential worse-case scenario.

   This margin is up to you and your judgment, which is tough to make when you perhaps don't know what types of things I'm typically wrong about.  If it helps, I would say label it *impossible* for the script to delete any of your photos, because it **does not** perform any filesystem operations.  If *impossible* is not good enough, then the clear precaution to take is to backup your entire *Photos* library beforehand.  Depending on the size of your library, this may range from simple to pain-staking for the sake of a near zero-chance event.

   What the script **does** do (obviously) is read and edit lists of keywords.  So, while it ought not to be possible, it wouldn't be foolish to consider that all of your keywords for all of your photos might just disappear.  Should you want to cover yourself for this unlikely event, then I provide this "scriptlet" that you can run beforehand in order to back up your keywords:

   ```
   property path : "~/Desktop/Photos.Keywords.Backup.plist"


   backupKeywordsToFile at path
   --! CAUTION: Uncommenting the line below
   --! WILL OVERWRITE ALL KEYWORDS FOR ALL PHOTOS 
   -- restoreKeywordsFromFile at path
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # HANDLERS & SCRIPT OBJECTS:
   use framework "Foundation"

   property this : a reference to current application
   property _0 : a reference to missing value
   property _1 : a reference to reference

   property NSDictionary : a reference to NSDictionary of this
   property NSString : a reference to NSString of this
   property NSURL : a reference to NSURL of this

   to backupKeywordsToFile at fp as text
       local fp

       set fURL to NSURL's fileURLWithPath:((NSString's ¬
           stringWithString:fp)'s ¬
           stringByStandardizingPath())

       script
           use application "Photos"
           property _M : a reference to media items
           property properties : [keywords, id] of _M
           property keys : item 1 of my properties
           property refs : item 2 of my properties
       end script

       tell the result
           repeat with i from 1 to length of its keys
               if (item i of its keys) = missing value ¬
                   then set item i of its keys to {}
           end repeat

           tell (NSDictionary's dictionaryWithObjects:(its keys) ¬
               forKeys:(its refs)) to set [success, E] ¬
               to its writeToURL:fURL |error|:_1
       end tell

       if E ≠ missing value then return E's localizedDescription() as text

       success
   end backupKeywordsToFile

   to restoreKeywordsFromFile at fp as text
       local fp

       set fURL to NSURL's fileURLWithPath:((NSString's ¬
           stringWithString:fp)'s ¬
           stringByStandardizingPath())

       script
           property result : NSDictionary's ¬
               dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:fURL ¬
                   |error|:_1
           property mediakeys : item 1 of my result
           property E : item 2 of my result
           property keys : null
           property refs : null
       end script

       tell the result
           if its E ≠ missing value then return its E's ¬
               localizedDescription() as text

           set its keys to its mediakeys's allObjects() as list
           set its refs to its mediakeys's allKeys() as list

           repeat with i from 1 to length of its refs
               set x to item i of its refs
               set keys to item i of its keys

               tell application "Photos" to set ¬
                   keywords of media item id x ¬
                   to keys
           end repeat
       end tell
   end restoreKeywordsFromFile
   ```

   In backing up your keywords, the script will have to enumerate the entire *Photos* library.  Therefore, regardless of whether or not you *need* the backup, running this script first will give you an indication of how slowly/quickly your library can be read.

Comment: That's quite amazing.  I ran the second script first just to be safe and it ran for a few minutes then died with `error "Internal table overflow." number -2707` at `(makeJSONString of me to fp given data:it)`. I guess this is to do with the fact I have hundreds of keywords and 50,000+ photos.

Comment: Yes, the volume of your library does sound like a likely cause.  50,000 photos is a lot for the script to enumerate as a collection all in one go, but it might be possible (although slower) to iterate though the list and retrieve the keywords one set at a time.

Comment: Before trying the individual iteration method, I decided to see if using another data type for the file would help.  I've updated the second script to use property list data instead of JSON.  In my brief simulation, I created a collection of data that would contained 50,000 keys paired with 50,000 values, and it reproduced the `"Internal table overflow."` error when this was attempted to convert to a JSON string.  However, with the same collection, it converted to a property list and wrote to file successfully.  I'd be grateful if you tried the new backup script and reported back.

Comment: that worked, and quite quickly too.

Comment: @DaveSag Hello, I'm sorry to have disappeared—health problems struck again. What was the latest with regards to this problem ?  It occurs to me that since the script used to backup keywords using property list data works with your large dataset, the original intended script can probably be discarded as the backup script also has a handler to `restoreKeywordsFromFile`.  Therefore, the simplest method might be to backup the keywords; manually delete all keywords from _Photos.app_; then restore the keywords from the backup file.

Comment: Manually deleting is what I really want to avoid.  I'll look at tweaking your script to just emit the names of the keywords without attached images and then that will make it faster to delete them

Comment: Did you give the original script a go ?

Comment: No I didn't.  I'll backup the whole photo library and take the Mac offline then try that :-)

Comment: If you're backing up the whole library anyway, then it would probably be more reliable to use the second script in the manner that I described previously.  Unless there's a specific reason you want to avoid manually deleting all keywords prior to running the restoration script ?

Comment: To be more specific, CJK's suggestion to remove all unused keywords is 
(A) run the Backup script above (second one)
(B) I would check and even Duplicate resulting Photos.Keywords.Backup.plist file on your Desktop
(C) go to Photos' Keyword Manager, Select All keywords (Cmd -A) and delete them with the Minus button and confirm
(D) Convert AppleScript to restoring by commenting out line 4 ( backupKeywordsToFile) and uncommenting line 7 ( restoreKeyWordsToFile line). 
(E) Run that resulting Restore script
(F) Check things are good and delete the keyword backup file

Blindingly fast!